# Ionic 2 - native transition on alertcontroller

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, modal-dialog

Is that possible to implement the native transition or animation (opacity etc) in alert controller like what we are doing in Modal dialog?

For modal dialog we can use like below code.

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SingleButtonAlertModalPage, { showBackdrop: false,
      enableBackdropDismiss: false,
      enterAnimation: 'modal-scale-up-enter'});
```

I want to implement fade in/out in alert controller. While alert dialog displaying it has to come from top of the screen? Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply custom styles to ModalController by adding cssClass.

```
{ cssClass: 'native-transition' }
```

In your component.scss file, apply the properties to class for animation.

```
.native-transition{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```